# Different response to same Excel formula in two different systems

Tags: excel, date, search, text

My objective is to read the text from a cell in excel, fetch the date in the cell and display the corresponding day of the week.
I was successfully able to do it by the below formula

> =TEXT((MID(A7,SEARCH("??/??/????",A7),10)),"dddd")

[Formula when the excel is fetching the date and providing the day](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hr5OM.png)

One of my friend applied the same formula in excel in his laptop but was not able to get the day of the week.
He was able to fetch the date but not day of the week

[Case when the same formula was not displaying the day of the week](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6R2pJ.png)

Comment: In addition to @pnuts: `23/04/1990` is only a meaningful date in EN_GB locale (United Kingdom). In EN_US locale it makes no sense: month 23, day 04 in year 1990.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to change the Date and Time formats.

For that, Go to Control Panel > Clock, Language, and Region > Region > Change date,time, or number formats.

In the Formats drop-down, select English(United Kingdom). Press OK and that should show you the required output in Excel.